# Disk IO in MySQL clustered index

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

[image]

I learned that the leaf node of a clustered index in mysql stores row data.

If data is retrieved from the clustered index, does not physical disk IO occur?

Comment: If the index node isn't already in memory, of course it does. How else can it be used?

Comment: *"If data is retrieved from the cluster index, does not physical disk io occur?"* also to add to @Barmar 's comment `SELECT <columns> FROM table WHERE <indexed_column> = '<value>'` can/will still need disk or memory I/O to get the columns data which is not in the index file..

Comment: Indexes don't prevent disk I/O, they just reduce it. Intermediate nodes are smaller than leaf nodes, so they can fit in memory longer.

Comment: *"Indexes don't prevent disk I/O, they just reduce it"* yes and no @Barmar it's way more complex then that statement... imagine if you would fetch a complete dataset from a table.. i would rather see 1 random disk request (1 * 4 ms) vs 1 random disk request foreach record when the index is used (n * 4ms) .. But this question moving way to much in heavy database thoery and optimizers..

Comment: Yes, I was simplifying. They reduce it in many situations, but there are times when the query planner determines that the index doesn't benefit.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB must fetch a page from disk if it's not already in RAM in the [InnoDB Buffer Pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html).

Once fetched, a page remains in the buffer pool unless it's evicted by other pages, or the MySQL Server process restarts.

While the page is in the buffer pool, subsequent requests to read that page read it from RAM instead of incurring disk IO.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Q: If data is retrieved from the clustered index, does not physical disk IO occur?

A: It depends.  On lots of things.

**Long answer**

I/O is the slowest part of a query.  (If everything is cached, then other considerations become the 'worst'.)  In guesstimating how much I/O a query needs to do, I like to make these simplifying assumptions:

- The fanout is 100.  That is, each non-leaf node in a BTree (data or index) has about 100 nodes under it.  In the OP's diagram, the fanout is only 2 -- a necessary simplification for fitting on a page; 100 is more realistic.
- Only the leaf nodes of the data need be counted in counting I/Os.  There are *many* cases where this is an over-simplification, but in a smoothly-running production system, this is reasonably good.

These two simplifications avoid the gory details that have already been pointed out.  Think about it -- non-leaf data nodes comprise perhaps 1% of the BTree nodes, so a production system is likely to get to where all of them are cached.

A "point query" might need an I/O.  A "range query" might need to read one block per 100 rows read.  Note that you never do "range queries" with UUIDs.

In InnoDB, an `INDEX` (including `UNIQUE) is very much like a clustered index, with the exception of what is in the leaf nodes.  The "rows" of an`INDEX`contain the column(s) of the`PRIMARY KEY`.  Those column(s) are used to get to drill down the data's BTree to get to the rest of the columns.

"Using index" indicates a "covering index", which means that *all* the columns needed for a `SELECT` are found in the `INDEX's` BTree.  In this case, the bounce over to the data BTree is avoided.

All blocks (leaf/non-leaf, data/index) are treated (almost) identically.  The come and go from the buffer_pool on (roughly) a least-recently-used algorithm.  This makes counting I/O essentially impossible.  So, I estimate.